# VBA Excel get workbook object from closed file or refer to Excel SQL Table by sheet index

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I would like to be able to define a `Workbook` object and get info about its `Worksheets` object without opening the workbook.

I have the name/path of a workbook and an index representing a `Worksheet` in it and I would like to get the name of the worksheet.

Furthermore, the reason I want to do this is that I subsequently want to refer to the sheet in the closed workbook as an excel table that I can operate on using SQL statements.

So ultimately I need to be able to construct a string such as "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" where "Sheet1" is the name of the sheet in the closed workbook referenced by the known index.

So a more precise question is can I refer to a sheet in an SQL statement by index rather than name?

But if not, is it possible to set a worksheet object to a sheet in a closed workbook?

This works but obviously I open and close the file. Thanks for any help/insight

```
Option Explicit

Sub get_sheetname_from_index()

  Dim full_path_and_name As String
  full_path_and_name = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & _
    Application.PathSeparator & "test_file.xlsx"
  
  Dim index As Long
  index = 1
  
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(full_path_and_name, ReadOnly:=True)
    
  Dim closed_file_sheet_name As String
  closed_file_sheet_name = wb.Worksheets(index).Name
  
  Dim x As Worksheet
  Set x = wb.Sheets(1)
 wb.Close savechanges:=False
  
  Debug.Print closed_file_sheet_name
  
  
  ' USe the file name here
  Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
  connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data _
    Source= " & full_path_and_name & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
  connection.Open
  
  
  Dim sql As String
  sql = "SELECT * FROM [" & closed_file_sheet_name & "$]"
  
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  
  rs.Open sql, connection
  While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Name, rs.Fields(0).Value
    rs.MoveNext
  Wend
  
  rs.Close
  connection.Close
  

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try [ADO connection to Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-workbooks-bfb26f12-ba6a-91be-7fd4-4aadf1ff1afa)?

Comment: Hi @astentx thanks fortaking the time: yes, thats what i'm doing but the issue is I only know the sheet ordinal, not the sheet name. I looked atthe link you quoted and I dont see in that how i can use the sheet ordinal to define the input table range

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sheet 'ordinal'?

Comment: Hi @norie - sheet index number - [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/refer-to-sheets-by-index-number)

Comment: Why not use Power-Query?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d

Comment: @shai-radio thanks for the suggestion. I don’t know about the product but will look at it. Do you know how that would enable me to refer to a sheet by index? Thanks

Comment: @JohnnieL this is a feature inside Excel 365 since 2016. It allows you to pull the contents of a worksheet(s) from a closed workbook, and then manipulate the data as you seem fit. Even add your own custom fields. It's worth your time learning it

Comment: +1 for Power Query since it is more flexible and visual way to manipulate the data: less code, less bugs and a lot of possibilities to work with datasets, not single cells

Comment: Thanks both - I'll look into that for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can get the sheet names, and the names of any named ranges in a workbook without opening the workbook.

Not sure how/if it would work with the sheet index.

```
Sub GetSheetAndRangeNames()
Dim con As Object
Dim cat As Object
Dim tbl As Object

    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Users\Norie\Documents\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml';"
    con.Open
    Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    Set cat.ActiveConnection = con

    For Each tbl In cat.Tables
        Debug.Print tbl.Name
    Next tbl

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @norie - this pragmatically works for me: I can just set up a catalog object and access `Tables(index).name`

Answer (score 1):

With Dao, you can get the sheet name by index number. index starts from 0.

```
Sub getDaoTableName()
    Dim fn As String
    Dim conn As Object, db As Object
    Dim tbl As Object
    
    fn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "test_file.xlsx"

    Set conn = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
    Set db = conn.OpenDatabase(fn, False, True, "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;")
    
    Set tbl = db.TableDefs(0) ' 0 is Sheets(1) : 1 is Sheets(2)
    MsgBox tbl.Name

    Set db = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```